# Add twilio webhooks dynamically from a multi-tenant django application with subdomains for twiml

Tags: python, django, twilio, webhooks, twilio-twiml

I have tested twilio's twiML api for sending and receiving text messages in application and it worked well.

However I had to ngrok the specific test sub-domain I was testing from as the receiving Webhook on Twilio panel. In real use case, because it's a multi-tenant application, this needs to be dynamic, not just a single Webhook endpoint e.g [www.first.mysite.com/sms-chat-bot](http://www.first.mysite.com/sms-chat-bot), [www.second.mysite.com/sms-chat-bot](http://www.second.mysite.com/sms-chat-bot) etc etc.

The question is, how do I achieve this either via twiml or twilio rest api (couldn't find a single documentation on this, as everything seems to favour Webhooks).

Comment: The webhook needs to be pre configured from panel you need to add routes in your application if you can place them in a table or function

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by add routes in your application? if you mean the Webhook url in the panel, only one can exist, hence the problem, while I have a multi-tenant app with thousands of isolated schemas, accessible by several sub-domain. Just to put in proper context, a particular route/view/controller can exist as one but accessible as an isolated entity by individual tenants through their subdomain i.e www.first.mysite.com/sms-bot, www.second.mysite.com/sms-bot, www.third.mysite.com/sms-bot etc etc you see, while only one /sms-bot can be in the Webhook settings on the panel.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can dynamically set the incoming webhook URL for a number using the [Incoming Phone Number resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource?code-sample=code-update-incomingphonenumber-to-use-a-new-sms-url&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x) through the REST API.

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but numbers can only have one webhook URL per SMS or Voice. So, if you need to fan out incoming requests to different URLs, you will need to write one webhook endpoint yourself, that can then send the requests on. But hopefully you're just looking for how to keep numbers up to date.

Comment: Thanks for the response, as per my response to @Yungandhar Chaudhari above, I run a multi-tenant application, so the use case is for the url to be accessible to individual tenant schema via subdomains e.g www.first.mysite.com/sms-chat, www.second.mysite.com/sms-chat, www.third.mysite.com/sms-chat. All subdomain have access to the /sms-chat controller but need to be called at different times for different cases because they are multi-tenant, while only one /sms-chat can be registered as web hook on the panel. That's literally what my problem is, I'll try out the link sent also.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to have one Twilio phone number that is used by multiple applications/tenants?

Comment: just seeing this. Pretty much, as the tenants are created dynamically at signup/registration, I am not in control of how and when they signup hence the need for a way to assign webhooks dynamically or at least be able to send and receive msgs via rest api like twiML does. The rest api works well for other use cases of ours.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand what you are trying to do here. Can you explain the use-case a bit more clearly. What are users of your application doing with Twilio phone numbers?

Comment: Hi again, it is a chatbot for a Queue system. Where you can text CANCEL, STOP etc back to the application.  The application needs to be able to receive text/sms from users and respond to those sms, which TwiML does perfectly. Is there a way to do what TwiML does with the rest api, as that seems to be the only option now to bypass the Webhook endpoint requirement. Provided it is request agnostic we are fine..

Comment: I understand chat bots, but I don’t understand what you’re trying to do with multi-tenancy here. Can you explain further? Webhooks are the best way to receive and respond to incoming messages, I just don’t understand the problem you have yet, sorry.

Comment: The platform is multi-tenant, just like heroku is, wordpress is, shopify is etc etc. Meaning each tenant have their own isolated database/database schema with isolated application data. By extension, each tenant will have their own chatbot application. Granted Webhooks are the best way, are they the only way? Because only one url can be registered on the twilio panel and this two url's don't belong to the same tenant www.first.mysite.com/sms-chat, www.second.mysite.com/sms-chat

Comment: If this is multi tenanted, then surely you would use one Twilio number per tenant?

Comment: Is there a way to receive and send sms via rest api instead of twiML. As I couldn't find any in the documentation on that, apart from sending only with rest api.

Comment: You can send SMS via the REST API, and you can fetch messages that you’ve received via the API. But I really want to understand what you’re trying to build here and get the best answer for you. Are you honestly trying to use one phone number between all your tenants when they have isolated databases, etc?

Comment: Yes we were, as there was no way to dynamically generate a new number and Webhook url for each tenant at creation/registration. Is there a link/documentation or resources that shows how to fetch messages received via rest API? That would be mighty helpful.

Comment: Good news! There is a way to dynamically generate a new number and webhook URL for each of your tenants at creation/registration. You can use the [Available Phone Numbers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/availablephonenumber-resource) to search for numbers and then the [Incoming Phone Numbers resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource) to purchase the number and set the webhook dynamically. It would be much better to give your tenants different numbers in order to isolate the communications between them.

Comment: Ok thanks, we will try that out. Can we also get the link to fetching messages via rest API? That will be helpful as well. Kind regards.

Comment: Here is the [message resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource). I would advise getting used to reading the Twilio documentation if you are planning to build with it. I would also advise ensuring that your clients, your tenants, have their own numbers. Otherwise they are going to end up sharing a lot of information with each other that you likely wouldn’t intend if you are giving them separate databases.

Comment: Thanks, I/We always read the documentation(s).